# Downstream pipeline not triggering when conditions complete

Tags: azure-devops, devops, pipeline

I am trying to trigger a regression test pipeline after the CI pipelines for Backend and Mobile completes on any release branch

Current behaviour

- every time I commit the regression test pipeline executes not waiting for the backend and mobile pipeline
- After the backend and mobile pipeline are completed the regression pipeline does not trigger again

What I would like to have:
After the backend and mobile pipeline complete on a release branch the regression tests are executed

```
# regression test pipeline
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: backend
    source: 'app/Backend CI'
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - releases/*
  - pipeline: mobile
    source: 'app/Client - Mobile CI'
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - releases/*

pool:
  vmImage: macOS-latest

stages:
  - stage: Tests
    jobs:
      - job: Tests
        displayName: "Execute test flows"
        variables:
          testResultPath: "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/test-results"
        steps:
        - template: templates/template-regression-tests.yaml
```

If I disable the trggers by doing the following the regression pipeline is not executed at all

```
# regression test pipeline
trigger: none
pr: none
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: backend
    source: 'app/Backend CI'
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - releases/*
  - pipeline: mobile
    source: 'app/Client - Mobile CI'
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - releases/*

pool:
  vmImage: macOS-latest

stages:
  - stage: Tests
    jobs:
      - job: Tests
        displayName: "Execute test flows"
        variables:
          testResultPath: "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/test-results"
        steps:
        - template: templates/template-regression-tests.yaml
```

Comment: after both are completed

Comment: Would you please help clarify: 1. If you want to trigger the test pipeline after both the backend and mobile pipelines are completed, or trigger the test pipeline when one of them is completed? 2. In which branch is the yaml file of the test pipeline located? In which branches are the yaml file of the backend pipeline and mobile pipeline located? 3. Do the yaml files corresponding to the backend pipeline, mobile pipeline and test pipeline have the same name?

Comment: all 3 pipeline YAMLs are localted in the same branch and same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each resource pipeline that meets the conditions can trigger the regression test pipeline. Currently, DevOps does not have such a feature that can restrict all resources to meet the conditions before triggering the current pipeline. If you want such one, you could submit a feature request on: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback.

Based on the current situation, it's suggested that you could trigger these three pipelines one by one. For example, the backend pipeline triggers the mobile pipeline, and the mobile pipeline triggers the test pipeline.

backend-ci.yml:

```
trigger:
- releases/*
```

mobile-ci.yml:

```
trigger:
- none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: backend
    source: 'Backend-CI'
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - releases/*
```

test.yml:

```
trigger:
- none

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: mobile
    source: 'Mobile-CI'
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - releases/*
```

Comment: ok, thank you, will wote on the proposal

Comment: @Jester, if my suggestions are helpful for you, in order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept my answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!